# Can I open a checking account online in the US without typical proof of residence?

Tags: united-states, checking-account

I don't have a utility bill, driver's license, or USPS card linking me to my address, just a lease that has my name written last minute in pen as an additional tenant. Is there any way I can open a bank account without having to verify my address? I'm a US citizen, and actually live at the residence I'm providing.

Comment: Have you tried taking your lease to a local bank or credit union? If they didn't accept it, what did they tell you that they would accept?

Comment: Talk to the bank and find out what atypical proofs they would accept. But sometimes the simplest answer really is to put one of the utility bills in your name, at least temporarily.

Comment: I would start with getting the drivers license changed.

Comment: I opened a checking account recently. It required little to no verification. My ID is even expired and it still let me do it. . . So you should be fine

Comment: If you don't drive, you can typically get a state ID with your address on it easily as well. That might help.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge and research.

As long as you are US Resident you can open bank account online with lots of banks like CapitalOne, Nationwide bank, Ever Bank and many more listed on link below.

http://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/banking/nerdwallets-top-online-checking-accounts/ 
(I am not advertising here)

and from CapitalOne bank policy is asking is listed below for legal stuff. As long as you have legal Social Security Number you can open an online checking account.

Check it out

[image]